# How to query for entity with key whose ancestor is not known?

Tags: google-app-engine, go

`A` is ancestor of `B`

```
type A struct {}
type B struct {}
```

How would I search for `B` whose string ID is `stringID`, regardless of ancestor? (B and ancestor A may not even exist)

```
ctx := appengine.NewContext(r)
a := ??? // 'A' may not exist, so what do I do here?
k := datastore.NewKey(ctx, "B", "stringID", 0, a)
e := new(B)
if err := datastore.Get(ctx, k, e); err != nil {
    http.Error(w, err.Error(), 500)
    return
}
```

Comment: You can simply pass `nil` for parent key: `datastore.NewKey(ctx, "B", "stringID", 0, nil)`

Comment: @abhink: If you pass nil, this entity will not have a parent. An entity cannot change its parent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ancestor entity may not exist, but its ID or Name must be known. Otherwise you will not be able to create a unique key for a child entity. Note that child of A and child of B may have the same ID or Name.

Also note that you may delete one entity and create a new one, but you cannot change the parent of an entity once it's created.

Comment: I was hoping to be able to do a partial key name search or something like that. By my design, stringID is unique, so thats how I test if B exists. I guess I will just make a key reference to B, although I will lose strong consistency.

Answer (score 1):

You can [create a key](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/datastore/creating-entity-keys) for `a` without actually creating the `a` entity (the entity is only created when you call `datastore.Put()`). You can then use that key to create `b` (or just its key, if so you desire).

As for the query aspect: you could do a [keys-only query](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/datastore/queries#keys-only_queries) for all entities of B type, then for each key check if the key's stringID matches your desired `stringID`. You can get multiple results - for entities with different ancestors - stringID is unique **only for the same ancestor** (or no ancestor at all).

Comment: I can indeed to a keys-only query. Thanks for the idea. Technically I can create key for a, but I would be ignoring an a->b group if it does exist.

Comment: The key creation paragraph was only answering the "'A' may not exist, so what do I do here?" comment in the code which I interpreted as part of the question :)